# Emitting a signal not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, emit

I have a class called dosecalibration which contains dosecalibration.cpp and dosecalibration.h. The class is associated to a separate ui form. On the form, when a button is clicked, a signal is emitted.

There is a connection within main window to receive this signal, however it doesn't seem to be working. The code is as following:

dosecalibration.h :

```
#ifndef DOSECALIBRATION_H
#define DOSECALIBRATION_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QDebug>




namespace Ui {
class dosecalibration;
}

class dosecalibration : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit dosecalibration(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~dosecalibration();

    double dosefactor;
    //bool dose;

private slots:
    void on_useCharge_clicked();

    void on_useCounts_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

//    void on_pCSB_valueChanged();

//    void on_countsSB_valueChanged();

signals:
    void applydose();


private:



    Ui::dosecalibration *ui;
};

#endif // DOSECALIBRATION_H
```

dosecalibration.cpp :

```
#include "dosecalibration.h"
#include "ui_dosecalibration.h"

dosecalibration::dosecalibration(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::dosecalibration)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->countsSB->setEnabled(false);
    ui->countsSB->setValue(ui->pCSB->value()*100/9.6);
}

dosecalibration::~dosecalibration()
{
    delete ui;
}


void dosecalibration::on_useCharge_clicked()
{
    ui->countsSB->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pCSB->setEnabled(true);
}

void dosecalibration::on_useCounts_clicked()
{
    ui->pCSB->setEnabled(false);
    ui->countsSB->setEnabled(true);
}

void dosecalibration::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    if(ui->useCharge->isChecked()){
        dosefactor = ui->pCSB->value();

    }
    else if(ui->useCounts->isChecked()){
        dosefactor = ui->countsSB->value();
    }
    emit applydose();
}

//void dosecalibration::on_pCSB_valueChanged()
//{
//    ui->countsSB->setValue(ui->pCSB->value()*100/9.6);
//}

//void dosecalibration::on_countsSB_valueChanged()
//{
//    ui->pCSB->setValue(ui->countsSB->value()*9.6/100);
//}
```

And mainwindow.h (only included the 'includes' and the slots):

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <AFE_variables.h>
#include <QMainWindow>

#include "FPGA/fpga.h"
#include "FPGA/okFrontPanelDLL.h"
#include "decoder.h"
#include "analysis.h"
#include "about.h"
#include "logfile.h"
#include "Graph/graphicsscene.h"
#include "Graph/graphdialog.h"
#include "Graph/qcustomplot.h"
#include "Graph/graphicsview.h"
#include "settingsdialog.h"
#include "dosecalibration.h"

#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <math.h>

slots:

    //Dose calibration

    void InitialiseGraphsAfterDose();
    void on_actionDose_Calibration_4_triggered();
    //void doseCalibrationEnabled();
private:
    //Initalisation
    void onStart();
    void AllocateMemory();
    void ConnectFPGA();
    bool CheckConnection();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    okCFrontPanel *xem;
    FPGA *fpga;
    QProgressBar *progressBar;
    QTimer *PlayTimer;

    LogFile *logfiledialog;
    LogFile *logfileanalysis;
    QString LoadLogFilePath;

    dosecalibration *dose;
```

and a snippet from graphing.cpp, which is a part of the main window class:

```
    //connects for dose calibration

    dose = new dosecalibration(this);
    connect(dose,SIGNAL(applydose()),this,SLOT(InitialiseGraphsAfterDose()));

}

void MainWindow::InitialiseGraphsAfterDose()
{
    apply_dose = true;
    InitialiseGraphs();
    qDebug() << apply_dose;
}
```

So the `applydose()` signal is emitted at the push of a button in the dosecalibration ui. The `connect` should mean that the value of apply_dose is sent to console, however nothing is displayed.

EDIT:

Placing the connect within an `if` statement to determine if it is truly connecting confirms that it is indeed working correctly.

```
    //connects for dose calibration

    dose = new dosecalibration(this);
    if(connect(dose,SIGNAL(applydose()),this,SLOT(InitialiseGraphsAfterDose())))
    {
        qDebug() << "connect worked";
    }

}
```

The code above successfully outputs the message confirming the connect.

Any idea?

Comment: Did the connect() succeed?  If it fails it may put a some info out in the application debug.  It is also a function that returns a bool, so you can put it in an if() statement and output some debug info yourself.

Comment: "apply_dose is sent to console"... if you happen to be using msvc, it will actually be sent to the output window in the IDE.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus sorry shouldn't have specified, I have been checking both and no output in either

Comment: @MichaelVincent placing the connect within an if statement confirms that the connect is indeed working. I am able to see the debug output, see edit for implementation.

Comment: Did you check that you actually emit the signal?

Comment: @thuga I've included a qDebug() directly after the signal, and this is displaying in the console/IDE application output. So I'm assuming this means the signal is emitted?

Comment: Indeed. Try running qmake and rebuilding your project. See if that helps. I don't see anything wrong in the code.

Comment: Also check so you don't have multiple instances of _dosecalibration_

Comment: @Zlatomir the only other instance is in main window when then "dose calibration" action is triggered. its there the launch the dose calibration ui.     dosecalibration d;
    d.exec();
    d.show();

Comment: So isn't that the instance that you use and you should connect the signal from?

Comment: I also tested pulling a bool value (which is set to true on the button press in dose calibration) into main window. the value is always returned false even after set to true. if i try to pull a double across i always get 4.91426e+252 no matter what I've set it too. very strange.

Comment: Think about how many instances of the dialog you actually need, try to fix and if you can't, show us more code, mainly the part where you actually use the instance (if there are many instances, do you connect for each of them?)

Comment: @Zlatomir you were right. Removing one of the instances seems to be working. Write as answer and I will accept. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the multiple instances of `dosecalibration`, or make sure to connect each one of those, if you really need multiple instances.